# Add offset to jquery position with .scroll() function & .find(selector) in DOM

Tags: jquery, scroll, focus

I use the following code to scroll (after click on a button) to a textarea in the DOM and focus the cursor. It works fine.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.test-comment', function() {
    if (obj_test.u != '0') {
        var commentsform = $(this);
        if (!commentsform.hasClass('disabled')) {
            commentsform.addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            commentsform.removeClass('disabled');
        }

        $(this).closest('#post-' + $(this).data('post_id')).find('#masonry-meta-commentform-' + $(this).data('post_id')).scroll(function() {
            if ($('#post-masonry #masonry').length) {
                $('#post-masonry #masonry').masonry('reloadItems').masonry('layout');
            } else if ($('#masonry').length) {
                $('#masonry').masonry('reloadItems').masonry('layout');
            }
        }).find('textarea').focus();

        return false;
    } else {
    // do something

        return false;
    }
});
```

.

BUT it looks like the following image. As you can see, the textarea is cut at the bottom of my desktop window.

[image]

Is there any way to set a offset (eg 100px) to my code to scroll further? So it looks like the following image and keep the focus function? Or any other idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the right scrolling top, by first getting the top of the textarea using `offset().top` and then adding in this, the height of textarea ( so that whole of this is scrolled in view ) and some extra distance ( e.g. 30 ) if you need to include the button below it also.

```
$(document).on('click', '.test-comment', function() {
if (obj_test.u != '0') {
    var commentsform = $(this);
    if (!commentsform.hasClass('disabled')) {
        commentsform.addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        commentsform.removeClass('disabled');
    }

    $(this).closest('#post-' + $(this).data('post_id')).find('#masonry-meta-commentform-' + $(this).data('post_id')).scroll(function() {
        if ($('#post-masonry #masonry').length) {
            $('#post-masonry #masonry').masonry('reloadItems').masonry('layout');
        } else if ($('#masonry').length) {
            $('#masonry').masonry('reloadItems').masonry('layout');
        }
    });//

    // HERE COMES YOUR SCROLLING CODE
    var $targetTextArea =  $(this).closest('#post-' + $(this).data('post_id')).find('#masonry-meta-commentform-' + $(this).data('post_id')).find('textarea');
    var textAreaTop = $targetTextArea.offset().top;
    var textAreaHeight = $targetTextArea.height();
    var scrollHeight = textAreaTop + textAreaHeight + 30; // added 30 to also include the submit button below the text area
    $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop": scrollHeight}, 500, function(){
        $targetTextArea.focus();
    });//animate()




    return false;
} else {
// do something

    return false;
}
```

});

Comment: Works fine. THX. In my case "- 200" instead of "+ 30" works fine, without "jumping".